# Get the max possible time of a date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

What I am trying to do is take a date in SQL Server and find the last possible hour, minute, second, and millisecond of that date.

So if the date is this: `2021-02-16 13:08:58.620`

I would like to return: `2021-02-16 23:59:59.999`

I have tried something like this but it is not working and I guess that I am missing something where it is converting the time and keeping the hour, minute, second and millisecond of that date

```
Select 
    DateAdd(MILLISECOND, -1, (Convert(datetime, DATEADD(day, 1, DateValue), 101))) as lastPossibleDate
From 
    Table1
```

Comment: You'll run into problems because the `DATETIME` datatype in SQL Server has an accuracy of only 3.33ms - so `23:59:59.999` will be rounded up to the next day - the max value that you can represent as a `DATETIME` is `23:59:59.997`. Best solution would be to use `DATETIME2(n)`  datatype instead which has an accuracy of as little as 100 ns .....

Comment: Just use LESS THAN and midnight the next day...

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the comment never knew about the DATETIME2(n) very good information

Comment: Please explain why you want this. If this is so you can use `<= end of the day`, don't..... Instead use `< next day`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn it into a date to truncate the time, add a day, turn it back to a datetime, subtract a millisecond...

```
declare @Test datetime2(3) = '2021-02-16 13:08:58.620';

select dateadd(millisecond, -1, convert(datetime2(3),dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, @Test))));
```

| Result |
| --- |
| 2021-02-16 23:59:59.999 |

Note if you use straight `datetime` rather than `datetime(2)` your accuracy is only down to 3ms. `datetime(2)` is the recommended datetime datatype to use.

Comment: Worked Like a charm thanks never knew of the datetime2 until you and @marc_s mentioned it

Answer (score 2):

Another simply way would be to cast your `datetime` to a date and just concatenate it with the maximum possibly time for your given precision. If you want accuracy to 3 decimal places you need to use `datetime2(3)`

```
declare @date datetime='20210216 13:08:58.620';

select Convert(datetime2(3),Concat(convert(date,@date),' 23:59:59.999'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another option via `format()`

```
declare @Test datetime2(3) = '2021-02-16 13:08:58.620';

select convert(datetime2(3),format(@Test,'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59.999'))
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I would use string parsy anything for date situations that could be done numerically..

Comment: @CaiusJard It is just an option.... another path from A to B... another tool in the belt... Depending on the use case, I may not use this either.  It is 2 functions vs. 4, and the outer may be optional.  Besides, sometimes you just need a hammer.  It may not be  pretty or sophisticated, but it gets the job done  :)

Answer (score 2):

For datetime datatype, the maximum value possible for time is : `23:59:59.997`

[Datetime from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

We can use [DateTimeFromParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to derive maximum possible datetime value for the day.

```sql
DECLARE @datevalue datetime = '2021-02-16 13:08:58.620'

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( year(@datevalue), month(@datevalue), day(@datevalue), 23, 59, 59, 997 )  as maxPossibleValueForDay
```

| maxPossibleValueForDay |
| --- |
| 2021-02-16 23:59:59.997 |